# Apache Beam not recognizing custom container arguments

Tags: docker, apache-beam

I'm trying to use a local docker image to run a Beam pipeline, but it looks like this image has not been recognized even after I follow the Beam documentation suggested steps (https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runtime/environments/).

I performed the following steps:

1. **Created a Dockerfile with my custom dependencias (pypostal and fuzzywuzzy):**

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM apache/beam_python3.7_sdk:2.25.0

## System Dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get clean

ENV TZ=America
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND="noninteractive" apt-get -y install tzdata

# Python package management and basic dependencies
RUN apt-get install -y curl python3.7 python3.7-dev python3.7-distutils build-essential graphviz git-all
# Register the version in alternatives
RUN update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.7 1
## Create User Directory
RUN mkdir -p /home/user


# LIBPOSTAL
# Install Libpostal dependencies
RUN apt-get update &&\
    apt-get install -y \
        git \
        make \
        curl \
        autoconf \
        automake \
        libtool \
        pkg-config

# Download libpostal source to /usr/local/libpostal
RUN cd /usr/local && \
    git clone https://github.com/openvenues/libpostal

# Create Libpostal data directory at /var/libpostal/data
RUN cd /var && \
    mkdir libpostal && \
    cd libpostal && \
    mkdir data

# Install Libpostal from source
RUN cd /usr/local/libpostal && \
    ./bootstrap.sh && \
    ./configure --datadir=/var/libpostal/data && \
    make -j4 && \
    make install && \
  ldconfig

# Python Packages
COPY requirements.txt /requirements.txt 

# Install Pip Requirements
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt


ENV PYTHONPATH "${PYTHONPATH}:/home/user"

WORKDIR /home/user
```

**requirements.txt**

```
fuzzywuzzy
postal
```

2. **Created a pipeline.py file with the following Beam pipeline code:**

```
import apache_beam as beam
import argparse
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import SetupOptions

from postal.expand import expand_address
from postal.parser import parse_address
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

def run(argv=None, save_main_session=True):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)
    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)
    pipeline_options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = save_main_session


    addresses_examples = [
        "465 windward pkwy, alpharetta, georgia, u.s.a.",
        "2018 colby taylor drive, 40475, richmond, usa",
        "19-21 city road, chester ,chester ch1 3ae"
        "no.12 lishi hutong, chaoyangmen ; nei nanxiaoj",
        "building b, 25 yuan da road haidian district,"
    ]

    class ParseAddress(beam.DoFn):

        def process(self, text):
            yield parse_address(text)


    with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as p:
        plants = (
          p
          | 'Adresses' >> beam.Create(addresses_examples)
          | 'Parser' >> beam.ParDo(ParseAddress())
          | beam.Map(print))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

3. **Ran the script using the command:**

```
python3 -m pipeline --runner=PortableRunner --environment_type="DOCKER" --environment_config="beam-text:0.1" --job_endpoint=embed
```

*(beam-text:0.1 is my image name)*

But I still receiving the error message:

```
No module named 'apache_beam'
```

It sounds that Beam is ignoring my custom container arguments.

Comment: You run your job locally from a shell terminal ?

Comment: Yes, I run it from my Linux terminal.

Comment: Where are you getting the error?

Comment: On my Ubuntu terminal. (no virtual env, but with beam installed)

Answer (score 1):

Add `apache_beam` to your requirements.txt. You need `apache_beam` to be installed  both inside and outside of the container.

Comment: I keep the exact same code and add apache_beam to my requirements.txt. It still gives me the same error. I double-checked and also have Beam installed in my local environment.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a virtual env to launch your you `Beam` job, you need to have the same `Python` packages installed in your virtual env and in the Docker image (of course also Beam Python extra GCP).

The packages for the virtual env can be managed by the `requirements.txt` file or tools like `Pipenv` or `Poetry`.

The runner from the virtual env will instantiate the job and then in the execution phase, the job will use the `Docker` image.

Comment: Didn't get it. My docker usage is exactly to avoid installing the packages in my local environment (not virtual env). But even in my local environment, I have Beam installed.